# html5 `<audio>` player media types for multiple stream links

Tags: jquery, html5-audio, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am in the process of building a website where people can stream online radios. (It is similar to Tunein.)

I have finished the data management component for the site (e.g. sending, requesting data etc.)

There are stream links in a MySQL table, waiting to be pulled and passed to the HTML5 `<audio>` player. The player is able to load enough data to start playing the station on major stations (Capital FM, Magic, Kiss FM etc) within 1-3 secs; however, **most stations never start playing**.

The stream link is definitely working (I've tested on WinMedia, VLC; it also works on their websites).

Does this mean that the audio player does not support the file format?

VLC shows:
Type: Audio
Codec: MPEG Audio layer 1.2 (mpga) (this is only 1 file out of the 5000+)

I added these while testing:

```
<source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="" type="audio/wav">
<source src="" type="audio/mp3">
<source src="" type="audio/mp4a">
<source src="" type="audio/opus">
<source src="" type="audio/weba">
<source src="" type="audio/webm">
<source src="" type="audio/flac">
<source src="" type="audio/mpga">
```

I have been researching this problem for a while, but I can't find an answer for this problem. I'm open to any solution that can resolve my problem.

Comment: Just adding `<source>` tags doesn't do you much good, the stream has to actually match that format, and be of a format that the browser supports

Comment: So are you suggesting to decode the stream on the fly? Its like changing the house color to mach our shoes color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

As I've mentioned above I was certain that the stream link working. Checked on VLC, WMPlayer, even I checked it on the original radio station's web player. 
For example, the link in their source code, also on the VLC was: http://server.link:8000/
I have no idea why the hell I added an extra semicolon at the end of the streamlink but its working, so the stream link now is http://server.link:8000/**;**
Obviously VLC and other major players are clever enough to add the missing character... who knows whats happening at the background, but its working.

I just went through the UK stations (537 each) and all working.

Now I am in a process to create some sort of app which will loop through my database, which will do some sense check on these links and attempt to play it. If play, then will release it, otherwise it will mark it as broken link and I can update it with the new link.

Woop woop! Now I can have my beer! :P